# Need help finding second largest number in a list. Racket

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, lisp, racket

I've been struggling with this question for a lot now. Could someone please explain the logic behind the program by using the simplest way possible possibly recursion?

Thank you.

Comment: You are expected to explain where and why you are struggling and show some code you have. (instead of just saying "the program")

Comment: Simplest possible solution: sort the list and take the second element. Skip initial duplicates if the elements not guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Have 2 variables (say x and y)

Move through the list of numbers

Keep largest in x and previous largest (previous x value) in y

At end return y value.

Remember to compare each value to current values of both x and y.

I have tested it and it works but I am sure you want to code it yourself. Take care to choose the starting values of x and y.

### Edit

With reference to discussion in comments (using -inf.0 as initial value as in answer by @naomik) :

```
(define steps 0)

(define (gt x y)
  (set! steps (add1 steps))
  (> x y))

(define (lt x y)
  (set! steps (add1 steps))
  (< x y))

(define (2ndLargest L)
  (let loop ((x -inf.0)  ; largest
             (y -inf.0)  ; second largest
             (L L))
    (cond
      [(empty? L)
       (printf "steps=~a;~n" steps)
       y]
      [(or (= (first L) x)(= (first L) y))
       (loop x y (rest L))]
      [(gt (first L) x)
       (loop (first L) x (rest L))]
      [(gt (first L) y)
       (loop x (first L) (rest L))]
      [else
       (loop x y (rest L))]
      )))

(define (2ndLargest2 L)
  (let loop ((x -inf.0)  ; largest
             (y -inf.0)  ; second largest
             (L L))
    (cond
      [(empty? L)
       (printf "steps=~a;~n" steps)
       y]
      [(or (= (first L) x)(= (first L) y))
       (loop x y (rest L))]
      [(lt (first L) y)             ; FIRST CHECK IF LESS THAN Y; 
       (loop x y (rest L))]
      [(gt (first L) x)
       (loop (first L) x (rest L))]
      [(gt (first L) y)
       (loop x (first L) (rest L))]
      )))

(define L '(8 3 4 5 6 2 7 3 10 12 -1 11))
(2ndLargest L)
(2ndLargest2 L)

(set! L '(11 8 3 4 5 6 2 7 3 10 -1 12))
(2ndLargest L)
(2ndLargest2 L)

(set! L '(8 3 4 5 6 11 7 3 10 12 -1))
(2ndLargest L)
(2ndLargest2 L)
```

Output:

```
steps=21;
11
steps=48;
11
steps=70;
11
steps=88;
11
steps=107;
11
steps=131;
11
```

Steps are more if current is checked to be if less than y first.

Comment: You don't need to compare with both `x` and `y` unless the current value is greater than `y`.

Comment: That, I thought, is precisely why current value needs to be checked with both x and y. Say x=10, y=8 and current=9, one cannot just compare current with x and discard it. 9 is the second largest value till now. A list for this example could be '(8 10 9 ...).

Comment: Yes, but do you really need to check `x` after establishing that `5` is less than `y`? I agree you need to check both if you didn't know which one was larger but when you do you might get away with one comparison per item.

Comment: I get it. Good point.

Comment: @Sylwester :  Please see the code in my answer above. The steps are more if less than y is checked first.

Answer (score 1):

I took a swing at this using `foldl` – It works similarly to mso's answer by keeping track of the two (distinct) highest numbers in the list using an accumulator `(cons x1 x2)`, where `x1` is the highest and `x2` is the second highest

This answer will return `-inf.0` for an input of an empty list or an input of a single-number list

```
#lang racket

(define (second-largest xs)
  (cdr (foldl (lambda (y acc)
           (let ((x1 (car acc))
                 (x2 (cdr acc)))
             (cond ((> y x1) (cons y x1))
                   ((= y x1) (cons y x2))
                   ((> y x2) (cons x1 y))
                   (else (cons x1 x2)))))
         (cons -inf.0 -inf.0)
         xs)))

(second-largest '(8 3 4 5 6 2 12 7 3 10 12 -1 11))
;; => 11
```

Comment: It should be second-"largest" and not smallest. Using -inf.0 is very good idea.

Comment: @rnso wups, I originally wrote the answer to find the second smallest but fixed it before I posted. I just forgot to change the name ^_^